# Error in updating MS Access database with Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

This code is not working. An error message pops up saying:

> Syntax Error (missing operator) in query exprssion `SubName = Gussing Game`.

Here is my code please help. I need this code to update the Microsoft Access Database.

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Try
        Dim Str As String
        Con.Open()

        Str = "update vb set AssignDate="
        Str += """" & txtADate.Text & """"
        Str += "where SubName = "
        Str += txtAName.Text.Trim()
        Cmd = New OleDbCommand(Str, Con)
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Con.Close()
        Con.Open()

        Str = "update vb set DueDate="
        Str += """" & txtDDate.Text & """"
        Str += "where SubName = "
        Str += txtAName.Text.Trim()
        Cmd = New OleDbCommand(Str, Con)
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Con.Close()
        Con.Open()

        Str = "update vb set Weight="
        Str += """" & txtWeight.Text & """"
        Str += "where SubName = "
        Str += txtAName.Text.Trim()
        Cmd = New OleDbCommand(Str, Con)
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Con.Close()
        Con.Open()

        Str = "update vb set Reference="
        Str += """" & txtReference.Text & """"
        Str += "where SubName = "
        Str += txtAName.Text.Trim()
        Cmd = New OleDbCommand(Str, Con)
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Con.Close()
        Con.Open()

        Str = "update vb set Comment="
        Str += """" & txtComment.Text & """"
        Str += " where SubName ="
        Str += txtAName.Text.Trim()
        Cmd = New OleDbCommand(Str, Con)
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Con.Close()
        Con.Open()

        Str = "update vb set Statues="
        Str += """" & txtStatues.Text & """"
        Str += " where SubName ="
        Str += txtAName.Text.Trim()
        Cmd = New OleDbCommand(Str, Con)
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Con.Close()

        Dst.Clear()
        Dad = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM vb ORDER BY SubName", Con)
        Dad.Fill(Dst, "assignment")
        MessageBox.Show("Record Updated!", "Caution", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message & "," & ex.Source)
    End Try
    Con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: If SubName is a Text field then every value for it should go inside single quotes. _where SubName ='value'_. Of course if the value contains itself a quote you need to duplicate the quote. Have you ever heard of [Parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i)?

Comment: Parameterize your queries! You are leaving yourself open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't quote the string scalar you compare `SubName` with:

```
    Str = "update vb set AssignDate="
    Str += """" & txtADate.Text & """"
    Str += "where SubName = "
    Str += txtAName.Text.Trim()  ' should be """"&txtAName.Text.Trim()&""""
```

I'll skip over what an extremely bad way of querying this is.

Comment: But it didn't updated. The same error message was displayed.

Comment: Did you fix the others too? You repeat the same portion every query.

Comment: Also, dates are surrounded by `#`, not quotes.

Comment: Thanks... It was a great help